# Get wifi address or Mac of lost ipod

Tags: ipod-touch, find-my-iphone

My ipod as lost

Using "find my iPhone" app, I know it's active near a 20 story building.

The iPod is registered on my profile, so I know it's sn. I know apple will do nothing to assist me, but I do have some ideas:

Is it possible to get the wifi MAC address some how?
Can I get the wifi hotspot that the iPod registered from?

If I can get either, I could do some wireless sniffing and get a better idea on what Dror to knock on.

Comment: Find my iPhone will not tell you any of this unfortunately. One thing I can tell you, though. If you file a police report and find an officer willing... You can have the officer call Apple HQ at 408-996-1010. If the officer asks for Apple Loss Prevention, he can file a report with Apple. This is the only way Apple will help with stolen goods, and even in this case, I believe it is simply flagged to be confiscated in case it shows up at a Genius Bar and the tech pulls the S/N up in their system.

Comment: Second thought... What if you tell it to do the beeping sound, when you are in the hallway of the apartment complex. Maybe you will hear its faint cries for help!